# RxJava run on subscription method every time an event occurs

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have an observable that on subscribe does a long operation but when a user click on a button I want to notify my observable to do again the long operation because something change.

I don't want to make a new subscription every time the user clicks on the button. Which is the best solution to achieve this?

I would like to know if is possible to use a solution, which use the rxjava simplified way to run code on different threads.

Should I use something like this?

```
BehaviourProcessor<boolean> processor = BehaviourProcessor.createDefault(true);

public Flowable<List<Item>> getItems(){
     return Flowable.create(e -> e.onNext(longOp()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .switchMap(items -> processor.map(notify -> returnItems(notify)));    
}

public void notifyChange(){
   processor.onNext(true);
}
```

Android Room library achieve this result, in fact when you subscribe this:

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
   Flowable<List<Item>> getUsers();
```

Every time you delete an item from database you immediately get the new list from the database in the subscription on next method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have `getItems()` return the observable chain that you have shown, return a shared observable.

```
Flowable<List<Item>> itemGetter =
  Flowable.create(e -> e.onNext( longOp() ) )
    .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
    .switchMap(items -> processor.map(notify -> returnItems(notify)))
    .replay( 1 )
    .publish();

Flowable<List<Item>> getItem() {
  return itemGetter;
}
```

This creates only on observer chain that you can subscribe to as many times as you want. However, if there are no subscribers and another subscriber comes along, `longOp()` will be called again.

If you don't want that to happen, then you should consider using a `BehaviorSubject<List<Item>>` to cache the value.

Comment: Ok thank you, these could be a solution, but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to subscribe again my observable. Instead I want to use only one subscription that receive new elements when an event occurs.